# Customizing Flex Charts

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am wondering if it is possible to customize Flex Chart to have grids like in this example: http://imglink.ru/show-image.php?id=bfcb5a0c5bbcfc20f3f21ef764ed79e7

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple answer is YES you can.
you can give a skin to each of the elements in the Graph, I worked on a FOREX trading application earlier this year and I was surprised from the level of customization you can achieve with it.

you will probably have to extend the chart to accomplish it but you certainly can achieve the look you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Avi! Thank you for your reply! Could you please give me direction to where is starting point with grids?

Comment: Sure, You should look t a couple of things.

1st, customizing the stroke of the line.

2nd, creating a skin from vector graphics using flash and consuming it using flex's css.

the blog FlexExamples.com has many examples of configuring and customizing graphs as far as I can recall.

Answer (score 1):

HI You can do a lot of things with charts. I have worked on various elements of it while working with financial firms. 
the primer from where you can start with is 
http://demo.quietlyscheming.com/ChartSampler/app.html

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to include grids, axis customization and many more things to Flex Charts. You will have to invest some time reading the [Flex Charting Components document](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Part7_DataVis_1.html) at Adobe livedocs, or download the [whole Flex documentation](http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flex/).